# How to force refresh Project pane in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sometimes I get the following picture in Project Pane:

[image]

I.e. it doesn't show some classed inside packages and/or shows empty entries for them. Need to restart entire IDE to have them gone.

Is it possible to have some refresh as in Eclipse?

**UPDATE**

Collapsing and expanding tree branch is working, but in many case I have dozens of blank entries spread all over the project. Would like to refresh them all. Collapsing the very root is very effort consuming.

Comment: In my experience, collapse and expanding causes a force refresh, otherwise, I believe it refreshes on its own

Comment: :shamed: yes it worked, just forgot about this behavior

Comment: Yeah, if you click on something, or you manipulate the UI, then it normally refreshes, if it hasn't already done so via its UI timed refreshes.

Comment: This is a famous issue, let's see when this will be fixed :) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101953

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the folder you want to refresh i.e. in this example javafx and select the "Synchronize 'javafx'" option